# Android function returns NULL while on firebase onDataChange shows it is not null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to get values from Firebase and add it into the list. I do it the following way:

```
ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;

    public ArrayList<Category> getCategoryListFromFirebase() {
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL).child("categories");
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();
        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot categories : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Category cat = categories.getValue(Category.class);
                    categoriesList.add(cat);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
        return categoriesList;
    }
```

Function returns categoriesList null, but in a loop it shows it is adding object to categoriesList.

How this can be solved?
Thanks ))

Answer (score 2):

The callbacks for listeners are asynchronous, they do not fire immediately, and may require a fetch of data from the Firebase server.  In the code your posted, the statement executed after the `ValueEventListener` is `return categoriesList`, not the callback code that builds the list.  The list value returned does not contain the results of the `onDataChange()` callback because it has not yet run.

Also note that a listener registered with [addValueEventListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) remains active [until it is removed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners). To get data one time, you should use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener))